# Disable Android Airpush License agreement window?

Tags: android, airpush

Following the Airpush tutorial I've integrated Airpush to my application and there is that window from Airpush asking to accept an agreement.

I press Cancel button in this window and Airpush does show advertisments anyway, that's fine.

I wonder if there is a way not to show this License agreement window at all. That is if there is a way to make it from the code as if my user has pressed the Cancel, without showing the window.